# Splitting attribute value and inserting data into columns in QGIS using Python

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to separate a string value from a field and then put it into its releated Field.

The field name are characters in the string and its value is the number.

"Field"=PT 100BC 20cd 19 is the string value

PT= 100, BC=20 cd=19.

the string is irregular.

the column names are the characters in the string and number is the value associated with it.

I have so far done this.

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

inlayer=iface.activeLayer()

inlayer.selectByExpression('"TRTMTHD1"=\'PLANT\'or "TRTMTHD1"=\'NATURAL\' ')
selection=inlayer.selectedFeatures()

for s in selection:
    d=(sl.split() for sl in s)
```

If they do the split the result is PT, 100BC, 20CD which I do not want.

Which command do I use to split the value in field column and then update the record?

After I run this

{from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils

layer=iface.activeLayer()
fc=layer.featureCount()
f_list=[]
for i in range(0,fc):
    feat=layer.getFeature(i)
    f_list.append(feat['SPCOMP'])

field_list=[]
for f in layer.fields():
    if len(f.name())==2:
        field_list.append(f.name())

layer.selectByExpression('"TRTMTHD1"=\'PLANT\'or "TRTMTHD1"=\'NATURAL\' ')
selection=layer.selectedFeatures()

for string in f_list:
    if string!=None:
        for fn in field_list:
            string=string.replace(fn,',' + fn)

```
list_of_field_values=(string.split(',') for string in f_list)
for fvl in list_of_field_values:
    if fvl !='':
        fd,vl=fvl.split(' ')
        print('field=',fd,'value=',vd)}



I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
# splitting the string
list_of_fieldnames = ['PT', 'BC', 'cd', 'f1', 'f2', 'f3']

string1 = 'PT 100BC 20cd 19'
string2 = 'f3 3f1 1PT 100cd 19'

for string in [string1, string2]:
    for field in list_of_fieldnames:
        string = string.replace(field, ',' + field)

    list_of_fields_and_values = string.split(',')
    print(list_of_fields_and_values)
    for field_and_value in list_of_fields_and_values:
        if field_and_value != '':
            field, value = field_and_value.split(' ')
            print('field=', field, 'value=', value)

# update field value
# the layer is qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer
# https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsVectorLayer.html

layer.startEditing()
# check fid, field, newValue parameters at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.6/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.changeAttributeValue
layer.changeAttributeValue(fid, field, newValue)
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. but i cannot hard code the value. the string changes through out the column. it is a irregular string and some value start with different characters like 'pj'.

Comment: the problem is in your string - there is no separators between fieldnames, but it is still possible split the with a little tricks

Comment: if you could please help me on this. I am at beginner level to Qgis and python.

Comment: @JaySharma see update

Comment: please look at update i made.

Comment: @JaySharma you are trying to use split with `list` but it is only work with `string`. I recommend you to learn the basics of python for a little bit before you continue.